# MySQL: Can't insert '&' in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, string, special-characters

I'm going from Oracle to MySQL.
Doing some migration of data.

BUT

I got some problem regarding strings containing the '&' character...
Can't get it in a table in MySQL.

Example:

```
create table tmp_a(inforad varchar(100));
```

Doesn't work as I want ...

```
insert into tmp_a values('Me, myself & I');
```

Doesn't work as I want ...

```
insert into tmp_a values('Me, myself \& I');
```

Any advice ?!

I don't want to go through Java, PHP, C or anything else, just core SQL :)

Comment: What exactly happens when it "Doesn't work as I want".

Comment: There should be no problem storing & - it is not a special char for MySQL - what is the problem you are finding

Comment: Well, it stop processing the insert statement and want an input for the variable 'I' ...
I just want it to make an insert and store a string like
'Me, myself & I'

Comment: Sounds like you are using a weird client or API. As PaulF noted `&` is not a special character inside a string literal (no need to escape it or anything). Your example works fine when I tried it.

Comment: The normal syntax, if the table contains more than 1 field is to specify the fields you want populated _insert into tmp_a (inforad) values('Me, myself & I');_  but as Vatev said works fine for me. How are you executing the commands. Do you get any error message?

Comment: Works just fine with the builtin client. What data is being into the table in your case?

Comment: This behaviour seems like Oracle's. Are you trying to insert into the Oracle DB by accident? Also, what SQL program are you using?

Comment: Problem "solved".
Changed client, from Oracle SQL Developer to MySQL Workbench. Works fine ...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem

Had a quick look at the MySQL docs for special characters: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

String literal special character escape sequences

**Escape Sequence** | **Character Represented by Sequence**

\0  |   An ASCII NUL (0x00) character.

\'  |   A single quote (“'”) character.

\"  |   A double quote (“"”) character.

\b  |   A backspace character.

\n  |   A newline (linefeed) character.

\r  |   A carriage return character.

\t  |   A tab character.

\Z  |   ASCII 26 (Control+Z). See note following the table.

\  |   A backslash (“\”) character.

\%  |   A “%” character. See note following the table.

\_  |  A “_” character. See note following the table.